# How do I force 64 bit integer arithmetic on OS X?

Tags: c, gcc, math, macos

I am trying to force 64 bit long integers on OS X 10.5.6. running on an Apple MacBook Intel Core 2 Duo. Here is my c code:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long a = 2147483647; /*== 2^32 - 1*/
    long aplus1;

    printf("a== %d. sizeof(a) == %d  \n", a, sizeof(a));

    aplus1 = a+1;

    printf("aplus1 = %d \n", aplus1);
}
```

Compiling without any switches yields the following:

```
$ gcc testlong.c -o testlong ;./testlong

a== 2147483647. sizeof(a) == 4  
aplus1 = -2147483648
```

Compiling with the -m64 switch yields:

```
$ gcc testlong.c -o testlong -m64; ./testlong

a== 2147483647. sizeof(a) == 8  
aplus1 = -2147483648
```

So the second version is apparently using 64 bit storage, but still generates the overflow error, although 2^32 should be well within the range of a 64 bit integer. Any ideas?

I would prefer a solution that can be forced from a gcc option rather than requiring me to change multiple lines of source code (my actual problem is not the above example specifically, rather I need to force long integer arithmetic in a more general situation).

Answer (score 9):

Not only do you have to use long long, but you must also change the printf() statements accordingly.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    long long a = 2147483647; /*== 2^32 - 1*/
    long long aplus1;

    printf("a== %lld. sizeof(a) == %d  \n", a, sizeof(a));

    aplus1 = a+1;

    printf("aplus1 = %lld \n", aplus1);
}
```

%lld is the code for long longs.

Apparently true 64-bit programs can use %d for 64-bit integers - I don't know if it's possible to configure it to compile in this mode.

Comment: Indeed, the printf format specification is the problem.  If OP's system has 32-bit ints and 64-bit longs, `long long` isn't necessary -- just changing the format to "%ld" should be sufficient.

Comment: Ok yes, ephemient is exactly right. It seems the problem in my original code was in the printf statement - changing to %ld fixes the problem without needing "long long"s, provided I compile with the -m64 switch.

Thanks!

Comment: Mac OS X 64-bit follows the LP64 model, which is (int=32,long=longlong=pointer=64); this is the most common 64-bit model.  Win64 uses LLP64(int=long=32,longlong=pointer=64).  ICC accepts `-DMKL_ILP64` to follow the ILP64 model (int=long=longlong=pointer=64), and GCC has `-mint64` for the same, but it's not available on most platforms and breaks compatibility with other libraries and system APIs.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C99, include `stdint.h` and use `uint64_t` and `int64_t`. Other than that, `unsigned long long a = 0x100000000ull;` should work too.

Comment: I second this.

And to print you could use the 'PRI' macros defined in stdint.h

printf("a = %"PRIu64"\n");

Answer (score 2):

Use the C99 standard:

```
#include <stdint.h>

uint64_t a = 2147483647ULL;
```

There's an excellent [C99 library overview](http://www.dinkumware.com/manuals/?manual=compleat&page=lib_over.html) at [Dinkumware](http://www.dinkumware.com).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
long long a = 2147483647;
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response! However that doesn't seem to work, either with or without the -m64 switch.

Answer (score 0):

The literal `2147483647` in C code is of type `int`. If you want it to be a `long`, it doesn't help to have a `long` on the left-hand side, it's still an `int` on the right.

Make it a long literal, by appending a 'L': `2147483647L` (upper-case is recommended, lower-case 'l' works too but can be very confusing depending on the font).