# Can an Objective-C program be compiled so that int is 64 bit?

Tags: objective-c, c, xcode

If I remember correctly, on some machine, `int` was 16 bit, and when we move onto the 32 bit platform, then `int` was 32 bit.

Now that Snow Leopard and Lion are 64 bit, can a C or Objective-C program be compiled on Xcode so that `int` is 64 bit?  (and "%d" or "%i" will take a 64 bit integer as well).  Or is `int` kept as 32-bit for compatibility reason?

(and if using 64 bit `int`, will it be faster than 32 bit because 64 bit is native?)

**Update:** I just found out `sizeof(NSInteger)` if printed in a console app by Xcode on Lion is 8 (it is typedef as long), and if it is on iOS 5.1.1, then it is 4 (typedef as int).  `sizeof(int)` is 4 on both platforms.  So it looks like in a way, `int` moved from 16 bit to 32 bit before, but now we do want to stop it at 32 bit.

Comment: 1. you can use `long`; 2. read this for extra information: http://stackoverflow.com/a/199472/188331

Comment: You also might get some good insight [looking at this very related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985008/how-should-i-declare-a-long-in-objective-c-is-nsinteger-appropriate).

Comment: what you're looking for is the int64_t/uint64_t types; if you want to force a certain number of bits for an integer, you must explicitly use the types which guarantee the size you require.

Answer (score 3):

Under the **LP64** data model, as adopted by Apple, an int will always be 32-bits. Some compilers might allow you to use the **ILP64** data model instead, as explained in the comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/799923/248062). However, you will likely break compatibility with precompiled libraries.

Answer (score 1):

> can a C or Objective-C program be compiled on Xcode so that int is 64 bit?

I have been unable to find a clang option that will make `int` 64 bits wide.  In fact, the platform headers seem to assume that it can't be.  Also, you would be unable to use any platform library functions / methods that take an `int` as a parameter (that includes things like `printf()` that specify `int` types in the format string).

> and if using 64 bit int, will it be faster than 32 bit because 64 bit is native?

I see no reason why using 32 bit `ints` would be slower than using 64 bit `ints`.  In fact, possibly, they might be faster since you can fit twice as many of them in the cache.

Comment: On 64 bit, 32 bit unsigned ints are definitely slower than 64 bit unsigned long. The reason is that for unsigned 32 bit, 0xffffffff + 1 == 0. As a consequence, it is not guaranteed that for a large array a [i + 1] is the array element after a [i] if i is an unsigned 32 bit integer, and that destroys many optimisations.

Answer (score 0):

To get a compiler where int = 64 bit, you'd have to download the Clang source code and modify it by hand. So with existing gcc or Clang compilers, there's no way.

But there is a good reason for int being 32 bits: Lots of code needs for compatibility reasons the ability to have 8 bit, 16 bit, 32 bit, and 64 bit items. The types available in C are char, short, int, long, and long long. You wouldn't want long or long long being smaller than int. If int = 64 bit, you'd only have two types (char and short) for three sizes (8, 16 and 32 bit), so you'd have to give up one of them.